# Interpretation of cdf of geometric distribution

Tags: interpretation, geometric-distribution

Given a geometric random variable $X$ with $p = 0.05$, I want to find (for example) $P(X \gt 10)$. Trivially, this is $1 - P(X\leq10)$, which can be evaluated with the cdf as $1-0.4013$ or $0.5987$. That means the probability that the number of failures before I get my first success is *larger* than 10 is about $59.87$%. What I don't get is: $0.5987=0.95^{10}$, or *exactly* 10 failures...! How is it that this gives me the probability of having *more* than 10 failures? To me, $0.5688=0.95^{11}$ seems like a much more reasonable value: I got 11 failures, which is the bare minimum for having *more* than 10 failures... any further failures will be included in my $P(X\gt10)$. I know I'm wrong, but I'd appreciate some help in understanding why.

Comment: I realize I made a mistake in the question: I am implying that $P(X=10)=0.95^{10}$, which is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after reading through the Wikipedia article on the Geometric distribution, I believe I understand the problem. There are two ways to interpret what the Geometric distribution means: (1) the number of trials needed to get the first success; or (2) the number of *failures* needed before the first success. Both have different CDFs: for (1) it's $P(X \leq k)= 1-(1-p)^k$, and for (2) it's $P(X \leq k)= 1-(1-p)^{k+1}$. The problem I was trying to solve explicitly defined itself as "the number of failures before your first success", or (2), but (for some reason) expected me to solve it using the CDF from (1). For completion, by following the CDF from (2), we get $P(X\gt10)=1-P(X \leq 10)=1-(1-(1-0.05)^{10+1})=0.95^{11}=0.5688$, as I initially expected. On the other hand, the CDF from (1) results in $0.95^{10}$, which is what the problem expected.

Answer (score 3):

The event $(X > 10)$ is the *union* of the disjoint events $(X=11), (X=12),(X=13), \cdots$ and so $P(X>10)$ is the *sum* of the probabilities of these events. The hard way of calculating $P(X>10)$ is to sum the (geometric) series to arrive at $0.95^{10}$. The easier way to get to the same answer is by musing on the fact that the only way that the event $(X>10)$ can occur, that is, the *first* success to occur on the 11th or 12th or 13th or... is for the first ten trials to have ended in failure, and this has probability $0.95^{10}$ of occurring.

Comment: But what confuses me is that the problem I was trying to solve described $X$ as "the number of failed trials before you get a success". In that case, the event ($X\gt10$) would not mean the first success to occur on the 11th or 12th or...; it would mean *more than 10 failures before a success*. If the success is in the 11th trial, then ($X=10$), which should not be included in that. It doesn't help that I tried to compute ($X\leq10$) as $0.05*\sum_{i=0}^{10}0.95^i$ and got $0.4312$, which confirmed again my initial thought of the correct result being $0.5688$.